# openGl glrotatef explanation

Tags: opengl, graphics

I'm confused about the parameters of glRotatef

```
glRotatef(
  GLfloat angle,
  GLfloat x,
  GLfloat y,
  GLfloat z
);
```

More specifically, I'm confused about the x,y,z points. If I want to rotate an object around the origin, but 10 spaces away, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first glRotatef (and the entire fixed function pipeline) is deprecated in favor of shaders and managing your own transformation matrices.

second they indicate the axis of the 3D rotation (just use 0,0,1 if you are only in 2D)

to rotate a around a point that is not the origin you need to translate that point to the origin, do the rotation and then translate back.